# After 1 year and a half, my windows now decided to say its not genuine

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-genuine-advantage

On 18/06/2015 I bought a windows 7 ultimate key. I activated it, connected to microsoft, updated, and everything was nice.

However, to my surprise, today it started saying that its not genuine.

My first reaction was "I'm going to contact the seller! I'm sure he can help me!". Nope. Website doesn't exist anymore. I now think my Windows is actually not genuine indeed.

If I try to apply the activation backup, it doesn't work.

If I try to insert the key again, it says that the key is blocked by microsoft.

If I say I want to buy a new license, it doesn't offer me the option for windows 7, only windows 10.

I use some acessibility things, so I can update for free to windows 10. However when I try to install it, it says my windows need to be activated in order to install it.

What are my other options? 2016 is here to say "I'm not over yet". Dammit.

I'm from Brazil, and the automated call is not an option.

Comment: to diagnostic such non genuine messages, please run the Microsoft Genuine Diagnostics Tool (MGADiag : http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=52012 . Inside the tool click "Copy" and paste the output here.

Comment: Simply solution: Call the Microsoft Activation Center and activate your Windows installation

Comment: I've found a solution and posted as answer. Thanks for your input!

Comment: Why is the automated call system  not an option?

Comment: It didnt show for me at least. There just wasnt an option

Answer (score 1):

So, I found a youtube video that mentioned to run `slmgr -rearm` on cmd with administrator privileges and restart the pc.

Just that. No installing things or deleting things. And it worked.

Comment: I Googled “slmgr rearm” and found several pages (such as [How to use Windows 7 for free for 120 days, legally](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2009/08/how-to-use-windows-7-for-free-for-120-days-legally/)) that say that Windows 7 gives you a 30-day grace period to operate a system with an unactivated key, and this command just extends the grace period.   And it can be done only four times.   It looks like this is only a temporary solution.

Comment: But it doesnt show anything like "You have 30 days to activate your windows". It just says that it is activated

Comment: I suppose we'll know in 20 more days.

Comment: We will indeed. I promisse I'll give a return.